# Positioning nodes equally distanced inside a vertical rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

As in the following picture I am trying to put the numbers/nodes inside that vertical rectangle in fixed distance between one another.

Is there a better way to position those number?! or an easy way to calculate the proper coordinates?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
\centering 

\begin{tikzpicture}   
% 
% A Rectangle
\draw (0, 0) rectangle (0.5, 3);

% adding numbers :( so boring
\node at (0.25, 3 - 0.25) {1}; % the top number; 
\node at (0.25, 3 - 0.69) {0};
\node at (0.25, 1.3 + 0.6) {0};
\node at (0.25, 1.25) {\vdots};
\node at (0.25, 0.25) {0};



\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a macro that does the vertical fit. The first argument is the upper coordinate, the second is the lower coordinate, and the third is a comma-separated list of entries.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc}
\newcommand{\FitIntoRectangle}[4][]{
\path let \p1 = #2, \p2 = #3, \n1 = {abs(\y1-\y2-4pt)} in \pgfextra{\xdef\Dist{\n1}};  
\typeout{\the\baselineskip}
\foreach \X[count=\Y] in {#4} {\xdef\Num{\Y}}
\foreach \X[count=\Y] in {#4} {
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Pos}{(2pt+\the\baselineskip/2)/\Dist
+((\Y-1)/(\Num-1))*(\Dist-4pt-\the\baselineskip)/\Dist}\typeout{\Y,\X,\Pos}
\path #2 -- #3 node[pos=\Pos] (num-\Y){\X} ;
}
\node[fit=(num-1) (num-\Num),draw,inner sep=2pt] (Box){};
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\FitIntoRectangle{(0,0)}{(0,-4)}{1,0,0,0,0,1}  
% just to check that the thing works
\draw (0,0) circle (1pt); \draw (0,-4) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

You could, for instance, use a matrix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
mymat/.style={draw,
    matrix of math nodes,
    align=center,
},
}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
\centering 

\begin{tikzpicture}   
\matrix[mymat]  (mat1)
{  1\\
   0\\
   0\\
   $\vdots$\\
   0\\ 
};% 
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The entries are automatically nodes, and the spacing is easy to control. Placing it is also easy, if you do more advanced things, I'd recommend to load the `positioning` library as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
mymat/.style={draw,
row sep=0.1cm,
    matrix of math nodes,
    align=center,
},
}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
\centering 

\begin{tikzpicture}   
\draw (0,0) -- (0,-2);
\matrix[mymat,at={(2,0)},anchor=north]  (mat1)
{  1\\
   0\\
   0\\
   $\vdots$\\
   0\\ 
};% 
\draw[latex-latex] (mat1-1-1) to[out=0,in=0] (mat1-3-1);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: At first thank you, but how I didn't figure out how to change the matrix position.

Comment: Also, I have a constraint; that vertical rectangle is a part of a bigger complex figure, what I need is to distribute the numbers equally spaced inside the rectangle, I cannot change the rectangle size, because something else depends on it. the rectangle length is fine.

Comment: But your answer does not solve the problem :(
It does not work with my case, because in your solution the length of the rectangle depends on how many nodes inside it.
I may make a change in the code to use your way, I it worked, I'll accept your answer immediately. Thank You.

Comment: I am sorry If the question is coined in a confusing way, I will make it clearer.